# C# Nested ConcurrentDictionary wrapper

Tags: c#, c#-7.0

There seem to be no way to nest ConcurrentDictionary so that they share one lock

I am trying to create a class that will wrap a 3-deep nested dictionary with a lock

So that I can do NestedDict[k1][k2][k3] and get a value in a concurrent safe way
And do NestedDict[k1][k2] and get a ConcurrentDictionary or equivalent.

I am not looking for a solution inheriting or composing `ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<TK1,TK2,TK3>,V>` as it is not the same, it will not allow me to ie efficiently get all keys of dict[k1, k2]

How can this be implemented ?

Is there an existing generic library/code showing such nested dictionary implementation (including iterators etc) ?

Comment: What is the contract that you want this class to implement? (as in: what thread safety guarantees should it make) Maybe a concurrent dictionary wrapper will do here. You don't have to inherit per se, you can also implement the IDictionary interface and use a private dictionary instead.

Comment: Using three levels of nested generics is almost always a code smell anyway, I would strongly recommend looking to refactor that code and simplify it.

Comment: the contract should be exactly the same as that of ConcurrentDictionary however I am not sure of the locking implication of inheriting from nested ConcurrentDictionarys .. I can implement IDictionary myself like you said but still my question is how to override nested access []

Comment: Could you  implement `this[K1, K2, K3]` instead?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 thanks, I can but that's what I was trying to avoid with my question

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . _Why_ do you need this?

Comment: Why don't you approach this as a ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<K1, K2, K3>>,V>? Your wrapper class can dumb it down to [K1,K2,K3] and internally create the tuple if you need. Then you don't need to worry about multiple locks.

Comment: @kofifus what is the actual problem you want to solve? ConcurrentDictionary *doesn't* need locks, that's why it's usefull. The prhase `nest ConcurrentDictionary so that they share one lock` doesn't make much sense. Why would you want to nest any type of dictionary anyway instead of using *objects* with ConcurrentDictionary properties? Simply addressing an element two levels down would be a nightmare

Comment: @kofifus the key doesn't have to be a simple type. It can be any type that has a meaningful Equals and GetHashCode. A ValueTuple could be more than enough. If you want to create a "simpler" accessor, just create an extension method

Answer (score 2):

Here is one approach that you can take

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;

public class Program
{
    public class NestedDictionary<TK1, TK2, TK3, TValue>
    {
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<TK1, TK2, TK3>, TValue> storage = new ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<TK1, TK2, TK3>, TValue>();
        public TValue this[TK1 key1, TK2 key2, TK3 key3]
        {
            get => this.storage[new Tuple<TK1, TK2, TK3>(key1, key2, key3)];
            set => this.storage[new Tuple<TK1, TK2, TK3>(key1, key2, key3)] = value;
        }

        public bool TryGetValue(TK1 key1, TK2 key2, TK3 key3, out TValue value)
        {
            return this.storage.TryGetValue(new Tuple<TK1, TK2, TK3>(key1, key2, key3), out value);
        }

        public bool TryAdd(TK1 key1, TK2 key2, TK3 key3, TValue value)
        {
            return this.storage.TryAdd(new Tuple<TK1, TK2, TK3>(key1, key2, key3), value);
        }

        // etc etc

    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        NestedDictionary<int, bool, DateTime, string> d = new NestedDictionary<int, bool, DateTime, string>();
        d[1, false, new DateTime(2018, 6, 18)] = "Hello";
        d[1, true, new DateTime(2018, 6, 18)] = "World";
        d[2, false, new DateTime(2018, 6, 18)] = "Foo";
        d[2, false, new DateTime(2018, 6, 19)] = "Bar";
        Console.WriteLine(d[1, true, new DateTime(2018, 6, 18)]); // World
    }
}
```

You could even at a pinch implement the IDictionary methods. Given that Tuple internally gives you a good spread on your hashcodes from the composite keys, it should have very similar performance characteristics of three separate dictionaries in a nest.

Comment: A wrapper isn't needed - those methods could be extension methods. If the key is a ValueTuple, the tuple syntax is probably *simpler* than either the wrapper or the extension methods, eg `var dict=new ConcurrentDictionary<(int,bool,DateTime), string>();  dict[ (1,false,new DateTime(....))]= "Hello";`

Comment: Thanks, The problem with this is that NestedDictionary does not implement the full Dictionary interface (ie iterators etc).

Comment: Your iterators like keys need to be an ienumerable<T>, so in context of you wanting a custom consumer to take three arguments it made no sense to me. If you were happy with keys being a tuple, then you could inherit NestedDictionary from ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<TK1,TK2,TK3>,TValue> and then use 'this' instead of 'this.storage' on those overloads.

Comment: inheriting or composing ConcurrentDictionary<Tuple<TK1,TK2,TK3>,TValue> is not the same, it will not allow me to ie efficiently get all keys of dict[k1, k2]

Comment: A Dictionary<string> doesn't let you see all keys starting with 'A' either even though a string is (in concept at least) a sequenced collection of characters.  Please update your question to explain what you want to do. There is too much scope in your use of the word 'etc' for us to make any further sensible suggestions.

Comment: Dictionary<string, <Dictionary<string, string>> allows me to do d["key"].Keys, I want the same for concurrent dictionary